# Bundle loopback with webpack

Tags: webpack, bundle, loopback

Is there a way to bundle the loopback server with Webpack?

I tried but it does not work at all.

My guess is that it is something related with the way loopback boots.

And also about all .json and .js configuration files (e.g. config.json) that are not included into the bundle by Webpack since they are not imported into the code.